# Call my view from celery task which will hit the third party API and save data into database

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, celery

I want to call my view from celery task which will hit the API and save the respective data into database.

```
def test_task():
    # view_url = "domain/api/v1/id/connection"
    objects = Model.objects.all()
    for ob in objects:
        # get the id and for each id calll the test view
    




def testView(request):
    instance = self.self.get_object()
    #do the task
```

This is my celery task and view that I  want to access from that celery task

** My thought**
I thought of making url and just adding id to the url and then using the request module to make the request on that view.

example :

````
def test_task():
    objects = Model.objects.all()
    for ob in objects:
         view_url = "domain/api/v1/%s/connection" % ob.id
         request.get(view_url)
        ```
````

Comment: It sounds like you're putting your business logic in the view.  Is there a reason you can't move that logic into its own service function, which can be called from either the view or the celery task?

Comment: I could but I thought if I could achieve this without changing the code that would be better

Comment: I'd suggest it's better to change the code.  Adding URLs, requests, responses, etc. into the mix will make it fragile, harder to test, and harder to debug.